# A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OAuthCredentials

Tags: azure, powershell

i am out of options someone here who can help me, what is wrong on my script?

```
$AADcredential = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserPasswordCredential -ArgumentList $Credentials.UserName.ToString(), $Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password.ToString()
$token = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($Context,"https://outlook.office365.com", $ClientId, $AADcredential).result
$service.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OAuthCredentials($token.AccessToken)
```

Thanks in advance to push me in the right direction

Comment: try: `$service.Credentials = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OAuthCredentials]$token.AccessToken`

Comment: `.AccessToken` is a string, and the only constructor overload that takes a string requires a base64-encoded string, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.oauthcredentials?view=exchange-ews-api"